Gave up waiting for root file system device, Missing modules
(initramfs) exit
Gave up waiting for root file system device. Common problems:
Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; 1s/dev)
ALERT! UUID=93b4291a-afb4-40eb-9f0e-f6d7ce6b003b does not exist. Dropping to a shell!
BusyBox v1.30.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.30.1-7ubuntu3.1) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.
(initramfs)


Failed hard drive, missing partition, bad edit to fstab.

In the boot menu select Ubuntu, dont press Enter, press the E letter to edit the menuentry.
In the line that start with Linux word replace root=UUID=93b4291a-afb4-40eb-9f0e-f6d7ce6b003b with root=/dev/sda1, and press F10.
When you reach the desktop apply this command:
sudo update-grub

If you know the partition number write the correct value instead of /dev/sda1. if you don't know it, before pressing the E letter, press the C letter, write ls and press Enter. you will see the number of all partitions. back to the menuentry try one by one to boot with Ubuntu.
You can use live session to know the details of Ubuntu partition by the disk utility, and to edit this value in /boot/grub/grub.cfg, and  /etc/fstab. reboot as the normal state.
